# Using .include in my repo findbyid 

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I have the following function in my generic repository which works fine:

```
public IQueryable<T> FindWhere(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params string[] includes)
{
        IQueryable<T> query = _dbSet;

        foreach (var child in includes)
        {
            query = query.Include(child);
        }

        return query.Where(predicate);            
}
```

I then also have this to find a single item:

```
public T FindById(int id)
{
        return _dbSet.Find(id);
}
```

What I need is an override for `FindById` that will allow me to pass in `params string[]` includes to allow me to eager load properties on the individual item found.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the entity entry to load the related entities, however you need to know relationship multiplicity:

```
entity = _dbSet.Find(id);

// Use this for a reference property
context.Entry(entity).Reference(propertyName).Load();

// Use this instead for a collection property
context.Entry(entity).Collection(propertyName).Load();
```

Comment: So I can't use a generic function then? Also sorry for the stupid question but where is context coming from?

Comment: There isn't a generic way of doing this with DbSet. 
I don't know enough about your code to tell where to get the DbContext associated with the DbSet you are manipulating.